# GitLab branching with production and test environments

Tags: gitlab

We create feature and hotfix branches from master (production environment), and merge them to staging (test environment) and once approved we merge our feature/hotfix to master to deploy to production.  My question comes about as master and staging are long living branches they could end up with differences in their content.  How would one handle resetting staging to look like current master?  And, are there any recommendations on the frequency of doing such a process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your development team always follow master->feature->staging and later feature->master, then staging should have whatever master has, plus modifications that didn't make it to master. So, **staging is a superset of master**.

What would be a problem is if there are scenarios where you do feature->master without doing feature->staging, in which case your best bet is to do master->staging to ensure staging will have what master has. By doing that, you will get "**staging is a superset of master**" like above.

Or, if your actual intention is to reset your staging branch to remove all the modifications that came from failed/rejected feature and hotfix branches so that **staging is identical to master** (that is before they start to diverge again), the easiest way is to abandon the old staging branch (rename it if you must) and re-create a new staging branch from the master branch. You might need to update your developers and any CI/CD tools that use the staging branch to pick up the new branch though, because the new staging branch is not a descendant of the old one. Due to the troubles that may follow, you might want to reserve doing this exercise to just monthly or quarterly.